# How to render the answer of a django api in a textarea?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

After I get the api response, how to format this response and put that in a given textarea?

Answer (score 1):

POST if you're adding new data.
PUT if you're updating existing data.

Comment: Thanks. But how can in the same time create data and send it to the database and get the back a response including this saved data?